# Combine all one-to-one relationship tables into a single table (MYSQL)

Tags: mysql

**==SOLVED==**

Existing tables

**sub_category**

```
-------------------------------------
pdcatid     | pdmcatid  | name
1           | 1         | Sub Category 1
2           | 1         | Sub Category 2
3           | 2         | Sub Category 3
4           | 2         | Sub Category 4
5           | 3         | Sub Category 5
6           | 3         | Sub Category 6
-------------------------------------
```

**category**

```
-----------------------------------
pdmcatid    | pdlcatid  | name
1           | 1         | Category 1
2           | 2         | Category 2
3           | 2         | Category 3
-----------------------------------
```

**main_category**

```
----------------------------
pdlcatid    | name
1           | Main Category 1
2           | Main Category 2
----------------------------
```

I am stuck on **how to create new parent_ids** based on the relationship amoung the 3 tables

new table: **categories** (Expected Result)

*The new pdcatid sequence is not important as long as I can maintain the correct relationship (hence: parent_id).*

```
------------------------------------------------------
pdcatid     | parent_id     | old_pdcatid   | name
1           | 0             | null          | Main Category 1
2           | 0             | null          | Main Category 2
3           | 1             | null          | Category 1
4           | 2             | null          | Category 2
5           | 2             | null          | Category 3
6           | 3             | 1             | Sub Category 1
7           | 3             | 2             | Sub Category 2
8           | 4             | 3             | Sub Category 3
9           | 4             | 4             | Sub Category 4
10          | 5             | 5             | Sub Category 5
11          | 5             | 6             | Sub Category 6
------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: You want to build a hierarchical table? Why? Are you expecting more levels in the future? You do know that MySQL does not support recursive queries, so such table would be hard to query in MySQL? My advice: If you can avoid hierarchical tables, avoid them. Especially in MySQL.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, yes, I already have that in place in most part of my application. I am running into problem migrating some older tables to the new one. I use php to build trees with parents and childs. I have to make a decision on splitting the new table to one-to-one tables, or merging the old tables to the new one.

Comment: You may want to have a look at Bill Karwin's great slideshow in hierarchical tables to know your other options: https://de.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, thanks. I have gone through similar article and have a general concept of that. I need to find the solution above and try not to use exhausting php foreach loop to update each row. But as we speak, I think I am getting there with two statements.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, I am planning to create the categories table using union all as shown and append the old relationhips there. Then run another statement to update the new relationship based on the old one.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner, I have managed to solve the puzzle! And I really appreciate your help. And I will never use hierarchical tables when I start a new application. Oh well, never say never

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to accomplish the above with following two steps:

```
CREATE TABLE categories (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY) AS
SELECT pdlcatid AS pdcatid, 0 AS parent_id, 0 AS old_parent_id, null AS old_pdcatid, name, 'pdlcat' AS cat FROM main_category
UNION ALL
SELECT pdmcatid AS pdcatid, 0 AS parent_id, pdlcatid AS old_parent_id, null AS old_pdcatid, name, 'pdmcat' AS cat FROM category
UNION ALL
SELECT pdcatid, 0 AS parent_id, pdmcatid AS old_parent_id, pdcatid AS old_pdcatid, name, 'pdcat' AS cat FROM sub_category
```

*Note: When I create the new table, I append the old relationships and alias of the old tables "cat"*

Then update new relationships with old relationships

```
UPDATE categories as t 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT t1.id, 
    CASE t1.cat 
    WHEN 'pdcat' THEN (SELECT id FROM categories as t2 WHERE t2.cat = 'pdmcat' AND t2.pdcatid = t1.old_parent_id) 
    WHEN 'pdmcat' THEN (SELECT id FROM categories as t2 WHERE t2.cat = 'pdlcat' AND pdcatid = t1.old_parent_id) 
    ELSE 0 END as new_parent_id FROM categories as t1) as t3 
ON t.id = t3.id 
SET t.parent_id = t3.new_parent_id
```

*And finally drop the unwanted columns*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do this step by step:

```
create table categories
(
  pdcatid int not null auto_increment,
  parent_id int,
  pdcatid_old int,
  pdmcatid_old int,
  pdlcatid_old int,
  name varchar(200),
  primary key (pdcatid)
);

insert into categories(pdlcatid_old, name)
  select pdlcatid, name
  from main_category;

insert into categories(pdmcatid_old, pdlcatid_old, name, parent_id)
  select pdmcatid, pdlcatid, name,
    (
      select pdcatid
      from categories
      where categories.pdlcatid_old = category.pdlcatid
    )
  from category;

insert into categories(pdcatid_old, pdmcatid_old, name, parent_id)
  select pdcatid, pdmcatid, name,
    (
      select pdcatid
      from categories
      where categories.pdmcatid_old = sub_category.pdmcatid
    )
  from sub_category;
```

(You can do the same of course with one union all insert and one or two subsequent updates.)

Then you can drop columns that you don't want and add a not null constraint and a foreign key constraint on parent_id.

I'd rather call the new `pdcatid` simply `id` by the way. (Or call it `categories_id`, but then call `parent_id` `parent_categories_id` for consistency.)

Comment: Thanks, I am trying. And yes, I will be calling it "simply" id. Meanwhile, can you take a look of my UPDATE. I have created the table as mentioned and trying to run second statement with sytnax error :(

Comment: Yes, it works except line 3rd from last should be: where categories.pdmcatid_old = sub_category.pdmcatid

Comment: Oh, yes of course. Copy and paste :-) I've corrected my answer.